# the difference between responseJSON and responseData of Alamofire

Tags: alamofire

I was just playing with Alamofire framework and making few api calls. However I observed there are two request methods in alamofire

What is the difference between  responseJSON  and responseData of Alamofire.

```
public func responseData(
    queue: DispatchQueue? = nil,
    completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<Data>) -> Void)
    -> Self
{
    return response(
        queue: queue,
        responseSerializer: DataRequest.dataResponseSerializer(),
        completionHandler: completionHandler
    )
}




public func responseJSON(
    queue: DispatchQueue? = nil,
    options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = .allowFragments,
    completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<Any>) -> Void)
    -> Self
{
    return response(
        queue: queue,
        responseSerializer: DataRequest.jsonResponseSerializer(options: options),
        completionHandler: completionHandler
    )
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`responseJSON` will pass a JSON object into its completion. i.e. it will be a dictionary or array with `String` keys and JSON compatible values.

`responseData` will pass a `Data` object into its completion. This may contain JSON data which can be deserialized into a JSON object but it also may contain any other type of data. Image data, HTML, video data, etc...

If you KNOW that you are getting JSON from an endpoint then use the `responseJSON` call.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using a library called `SwiftJSON`. Just wanna ask if I can use `responseData` all the time if I'm using such a library? Cause there is a certain endpoint in my API collection that returns an error stating that JSON cannot be parsed or something (using `responseJSON`).

Comment: @prettyitgirl.com if the data is not valid json then you will get that error. Only use responseJSON if it is json in the response. If not you can use responseData and it will just pass you the raw data instead (for instance it could be a file or some other sort of data).

Comment: Thanks! This particular endpoint works okay, the result is JSON, in Postman, but not in my project. It's weird really, error is 404, because content is in html or something. Figuring it out why it happens has taken much of my time, so I just use responseData and combine with `SwiftyJson` library.

Comment: Which is good for performance if i can use both? Any real-time experience ??

Comment: @iOS.Wolf5219866 don't worry about performance. Worry about what you want to do with the response. If you want something that is `Data` then use the `responseData`. If you want something that is a JSON object then use the `responseJSON`.